# Using insertBefore method in php

Tags: php, xml

I have actually asked this before, but alas the PC got nicked that I had the solution on, and I no longer can get the previous solution to work.

I'm trying to add a new  element to the XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
    <comments>
        <comment>
            <date>20120509</date>
            <time>10:21:05</time>
            <name>Lucy</name>
            <text>Hello etc</text>
        </comment>
        <comment> ...etc
```

The PHP code I'm using is:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->load(filename.xml);
$parent = $xml->firstChild;
$refnode = $parent->firstChild;

$new = $parent->insertBefore($xml->createElement('comment'), $refnode);
```

However, this adds a new "comment" immediately after the "data" tag, and if I try to add children (such as "date", "time" etc...) with `$new->addChild(tag, value)`, I get an "undefined method" error. I've tried all manner of permutations, but nothing works.

desired result would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
    <comments>
        *<comment>
            <date>20140225</date>
            <time>17:39:05</time>
            <name>Derek</name>
            <text>New comment text</text>
        </comment>*
        <comment>
            <date>20120509</date>
            <time>10:21:05</time>
            <name>Lucy</name>
            <text>Hello etc</text>
        </comment>
        <comment> ...etc
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the XML you to achieve as the end result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML file most likely contained the whitespace characters like in your example. These are interpreted as text nodes, which renders `firstChild` useless to obtain one of those elements you want.

You have to iterate over the children instead and get the first one, which is actually a `DOMElement`. Also you had to go one level deeper than you did. See appended sourcecode which outputs the result you want.

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <comments>
        <comment>
            <date>20120509</date>
            <time>10:21:05</time>
            <name>Lucy</name>
            <text>Hello etc</text>
        </comment>
    </comments>
</data>');
$parent = $xml->firstChild;
foreach ($parent->childNodes as $c) {
    if ($c instanceof DOMElement) {
        $refnode = $c;
        break;
    }
}
foreach ($refnode->childNodes as $c) {
    if ($c instanceof DOMElement) {
        $refnode2 = $c;
        break;
    }
}

$insert = $xml->createElement('comment', 'test');
$refnode->insertBefore($insert, $refnode2);
echo $xml->saveHTML();
```

Comment: No, that doesn't appear to achieve anything. I don't get any errors, but the source xml remains completely unchanged.

Comment: Please don't apologise, you are the one offering valuable help! Cheers, I shall give that a go.

Comment: Yes, that worked a treat. You're a gentleman and a scholar. Next battle is working out how to add the "date", "time" elements. My background is cobol. Does it show?